# Rails image_tag is looking at my production server for assets!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-management

I read that by setting ActionController::Base.asset_host, you can control where rails looks for assets.  However, by default Rails should look in '/public/...'

Somehow my Rails app knows to look at my production address when in development mode and I have not set ActionController::Base.asset_host anywhere.  I am not sure where it is finding this information.  Is there anywhere else this can be set?  I don't think my deploy recipes should have anything to do with it...

```
<%= image_tag 'my_logo.png' %>
```

causes Rails to check my production server for the file. Same with stylesheets.

Comment: Have you grepped you application for your production address? It's gotta be in there somewhere.

Comment: yes, the app and config directories.  the address is in there but not anywhere i would think would change this global setting

Comment: Can you post more information, ie an example method call that is fetching assets from your production address instead of locally? Are you sure your app is running in development mode? Are you using webrick to test or something else?

Comment: It's any time I use an image tag (or stylesheet tag).  I am positive my app is running in development mode as it makes changes to the development database. I am testing with "ruby script/server" for dev mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure how Rails knew to look for my production domain.  I removed it almost everywhere in my code.  According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html), "By default, Rails links to these assets on the current host in the public folder" but I am not quite sure what that means.  To prevent this from ever being an issue again and to allow some flexible configuration, I added asset host domains to my environment configuration.  I now have something like:

```
EnvironmentConfig = YAML.load(File.read(Rails.root + "config/#{rails_env}" + 'environment.yml'))[rails_env]

ActionController::Base.asset_host = EnvironmentConfig['asset_host']
```

Everything works great now. Still don't know how Rails knew to look at my production domain.